# Simulating Hardware security module

Tags: hsm

I want to implement part of HSM but first I need to simulate it in software.
I want to have a complete isolated enviroment(?) that works like real HSM.
My chosen API is pkcs#11 .

should i do something like cryptech,implementing pkcs#11 as rpc ?
Can i translate pkcs#11 commands and use one of the many cryptographic libraries that are available ? ( cryptlib & OpenSSL & ... )

PS : I know softHSM but i want something that i completely know how it works and i can configure it + good documentation which i didn't find about softHSM.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can share an HSM simulator which is based on the HSM's firmware and provides full PKCS#11 support. Would that be an option?

Comment: Thanks for answering. That's exactly what i'm looking for "what HSM's firmware doing" and simulate this layer. i'm not intrested in how cryptographic algorithms are done in hardware, i really want to know how PKCS#11 commands are translate to lower layers.

Comment: Excellent. Please fill out our contact form at https://hsm.secbss.com/pl/kontakt and we'll be sending You the download link directly.

Answer (score 5):

Some vendors provide an emulated/simulated HSM environment, at least:

- [Gemalto ProtectServer HSM](https://safenet.gemalto.com/data-encryption/hardware-security-modules-hsms/protectserver-security-module/)
- [Utimaco CryptoServer HSM](https://hsm.utimaco.com/cryptoserver/cryptoserver-sdk/)

But to be honest I do not understand your [SoftHSM](https://www.opendnssec.org/softhsm/) dislike as basically all you need to know is the [PKCS#11 API](https://www.oasis-open.org/committees/tc_home.php?wg_abbrev=pkcs11) (moreover you can see [the source code](https://github.com/opendnssec/SoftHSMv2) -- you couldn't ask for more insight).

Good luck!

EDIT>

[Given your comment]: The [publicly available](http://csrc.nist.gov/groups/STM/cmvp/documents/140-1/140val-all.htm) security policies of existing devices might be an interesting read to get some insight into HSM internals.

Comment: Thanks for response. The point is i'm not someone who wants to use HSM, i want to know how HSM's designed ( specially in firmware layer ). how they translate PKCS#11 and use cryptography libraries. I definitely admire SoftHSM as an open source product ( and i really love to know more about it ) but for someone like me who wants to learn whats going on "in" the SoftHSM, i found lack of documentation. ( surely i have lack of information about designing, but i really appreciate someone who help me in this journey )

Comment: @h-sh-h I am afraid no vendor would provide such information. See edited answer with an interesting source an HSM internals.